# C++: Simulate a deck of cards using two 1D arrays of strings to represent the suits and faces and one 2D array for the deck

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a program to simulate a deck of 52 playing cards.

Represent your deck as a 2D Array where the value in
the cell is the position of the card in the deck.

Represent the names for the suits and faces as
an array of Strings.

Write an algorithm to shuffle the deck.

Represent the names for the suits and faces as
an array of Strings.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int ROWS = 4;
    string suits [ROWS] = 
{
    "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades"
};

const int COLS = 13;
string faces [COLS] = 
{
        "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
    "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
};

int deck [ROWS][COLS] =
{
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13},
    {14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26},
    {27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},
    {40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52}
};
```

The problem: I am trying to connect the 1d arrays to the 2d arrays. Right now when I write:
cout << deck[3][5] << endl;
The output answer is 45. How do I populate the 2d array with the 1d arrays so that when I cout deck[3][5] I get it to say "Six of Spades"?

The way may teacher wants me to actually do the arrays though is by specifically using a 1D array of strings for the suits and a 1D array of strings for the faces and finally a 2D array of integers for the deck. I still cannot figure out how to populate the cells of the deck with the strings in the other two arrays. I know I would use a forward loop of some kind but I keep running into the error of the compiler not be able to populate an array of integers with arrays of strings. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, a 2d array can be represented in a 1d array using specific offsets.

Comment: "Represent your deck as a 2D Array where the value in the cell is the position of the card in the deck" this makes no sense to me, why wouldn't you want your array to be the cards themselves. Anyways, here's one mapping for you: [1:13] inclusive maps to all the cards of a suit, [14:26] maps to all of the cards of another suit, [27:39] similarly, [40:52] similarly. See if you can't do something with integer division and modulus. Also here's a simple shuffling algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: I've started c++ only 6 weeks ago and we only visit once a week. My professor is that kind that likes to give us problems and we use the book to basically teach ourselves. I've been working on this for three days and I'd really like to figure it out myself but two days of racking my brain and I'm just looking for help now. So yes, it is a homework assignment.

Comment: What really confuses me is the 2D array. Is this essentially meant to represent the cards being put on a table or something like that?

Comment: The way I understand it, 2D arrays are like graphs and this particular array is 4 rows and 13 columns and deck[0][0] is meant to represent the Ace of Diamonds etc. Maybe you understood that already but it's just the way my teacher wanted us to do it. He gave us pointers in class but we worked on it by ourselves until the end of class.

Comment: This sounds a bit "backwards", since you'll have a hard time returning the cards in any specific order (unless sorted).

Answer (score 2):

Start your deck numbering at 0 instead of 1.

```
face_index = deck[x][y] % COLS
suit_index = deck[x][y] / COLS
```

Then print the string using the indices to access the suits and faces array.

Answer (score 0):

Since I really liked the overall concept and I think that you might have misinterpreted the actual task (not 100% sure on that), I've sat down and wrote my own implementation of the program. Rather than constructing strings for the card values, I'm simply printing them to the console.

As with all examples, don't just copy and paste. Please try to understand. Also consider that you most likely won't be able to use this example 1:1 since I've done/interpreted things a bit differently. Feel free to use this for inspiration though. :)

The following code snippets can be put together to create a standalone program. I've separated them in a few sections so you're able to only look at the parts you're really interested in and to make it a bit cleaner to look at.

First of all, my program uses three include files/headers:

```
// iostream for writing to the console
#include <iostream>

// cstdlib provides the random number generator (RNG)
#include <cstdlib>

// finally, ctime is used to initialize the RNG with the current time
#include <ctime>
```

Similar to your own approach, I'm using two arrays of constant string literals. Note that I'm just using pointers here rather than `std::string`. In the end this saves you some overhead, since you're able to assign those to `std::string` objects as well. Besides that, your version is fine though. Also note that I'm using abbreviated names/labels, so it's easier to print everything without wrapped lines.

```
// Suit constants
const char *suits[] = {"D", "C", "H", "S"};

// Face constants
const char *faces[] = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
```

My actual card deck is stored in a 1D array since this makes accessing easier in my opinion. I'll be using some math shenanigans later on to calculate 2D offsets for determining the card names later on.

```
// Deck
// This array is populated below.
unsigned char deck[52];
```

The program is essentially supposed to print cards and shuffle cards, so I'll forward declare two functions for these tasks:

```
void shuffleDeck();
void printDeck();
```

Now let's have a look at the `main()` entry point of my program. I've put comments right into the code, since that should be easier to read rather than reading a wall of text and then having a wall of code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // First, let's put all the cards into the deck, one after the other:
    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 52; ++c)
        deck[c] = c;

    // Let's print the deck as-is
    std::cout << "Initial deck:" << std::endl;
    printDeck();

    // Shuffle the deck
    shuffleDeck();

    // Print it again
    std::cout << "\nShuffled deck:" << std::endl;
    printDeck();
}
```

Next is the shuffling function. This is also quite straightforward. I'll simply swap around values in my `deck` array to simulate shuffling. The standard RNG isn't perfect for cryptographic problems and such, but it's more than enough for this example.

```
void shuffleDeck() {
    // There are multiple ways to do this.
    // We'll just go through the whole deck
    // and reposition/swap cards at random.

    // Initialize the RNG
    // Since the numbers aren't actually random at all,
    // we'll use the current time as a starting point.
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 52; ++c) {
        // Determine the "swap partner"
        // This RNG isn't perfect, but should be fine for us
        unsigned char i = rand() % 52;

        // Now swap them
        unsigned char t = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[c];
        deck[c] = t;
    }
}
```

The last part of my program will print the actual cards to the console. Based on the card number in each and every slot, the program determines the proper suit and face associated with that index and prints them.

```
void printDeck() {
    // Access all cards of the deck
    for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 52; ++c) {
        // Get the card at index c:
        unsigned char card = deck[c];

        // Now it's going to get a bit complicated.
        // While the card array is 1D and the values are 1D as well,
        // it's still possible to interpret them as 2D: suits and faces.
        // To determine those, you're able to combine division and modulo
        // operations.

        // Determine the suit by (integer) division:
        // 0..12 -> suit 0, 13..25 -> suit 1, etc.
        // Integer division means the result is always rounded down
        unsigned char suit = card / 13;

        // Determine the face using the modulo operand (remainder of an division)
        // If you don't understand this, look it up!
        unsigned char face = card % 13;

        // Print the current card's suit, a separator, and it's face
        std::cout << suits[suit] << "-" << faces[face] << ", ";

        // Print a new line after every 13th card
        // c % 13 will be 12 for those
        if (c % 13 == 12)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And that's it. Please note that I put this example together in like 10 minutes. There might be errors, mistakes, or simply cases of bad style. Just because I did something this or that way, doesn't mean it's the perfect way to do this (actually, the RNG usage is a perfect example for this, since C++11 introduced a whole new API for this).

Example output:

```
Initial deck:
D-A, D-2, D-3, D-4, D-5, D-6, D-7, D-8, D-9, D-10, D-J, D-Q, D-K,
C-A, C-2, C-3, C-4, C-5, C-6, C-7, C-8, C-9, C-10, C-J, C-Q, C-K,
H-A, H-2, H-3, H-4, H-5, H-6, H-7, H-8, H-9, H-10, H-J, H-Q, H-K,
S-A, S-2, S-3, S-4, S-5, S-6, S-7, S-8, S-9, S-10, S-J, S-Q, S-K,

Shuffled deck:
D-9, S-5, D-10, C-4, D-K, S-3, C-2, D-J, H-5, H-2, H-3, S-6, C-K,
C-Q, D-5, S-Q, C-J, S-2, D-7, S-9, H-7, C-10, C-9, S-J, S-8, C-8,
H-K, H-6, D-6, D-Q, D-3, D-2, H-J, S-10, H-8, H-4, D-8, C-3, D-4,
D-A, C-A, H-A, S-A, S-K, S-4, H-9, C-6, H-10, C-5, C-7, S-7, H-Q,
```

Comment: Your random shuffle isn't correct.  You call `rand() % 52` 52 times, which results in 52^52 different possible results.  There are 52! possible arrangements of the deck.  Since the two numbers aren't multiples of each other, some arrangements must occur more often than others.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, I'm aware of the whole shuffling being skewed and far from being perfect.